# share models, libraries and helpers across both the front and backend

Tags: php, codeigniter

I created one application in codeigniter. But Now I want to move that to admin side. I have read 3 methods from http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter. Here I decided to use second one.

I that I created an admin folder in controller, admin folder in views,admin folder in css, and an admin folder in js to store the files like admin side controller, admin side views , admin css and admin js. I have set `$route['admin']='application/admin';`

And my question is:
When I access the file http:example.com/admin I am getting the page without js and css. How to solve that.

And one more question:
`$this->load->views('add_user')`. This statement changed to `$this->load->views('admin/add_user')`

Its difficult to change each and every page.

Answer (score 0):

You can share models and libraries between applications by using CI 2 "Packages". Have a look in the Loader documentation to  see how that works.